# C++ Vector push_back double free or corruption (fasttop)

Tags: c++, vector

I have a public vector in MyClass header file

```
vector<int> myVector
```

On the cpp file, I insert an element to the vector

```
myVector.push_back(2);
```

But I got double free or corruption (fasttop) error

How to solve this error?

Comment: If that would be the sole content of your code, you would not be getting an error. You probably have some memory problem somewhere else in your code, and it just manifests itself here. Try something like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: With the code you've shown, it's impossible to say for sure what your problem is. Please get into the habit of including a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

recently I encounter the same question as you have. It is because I use multi-thread to dynamicly allocate a two dimensional vector, with each thread access one column of the vector.

This may be your problem, so the allocating of multi threads may have overlap and conflict.

To solve this, I suggest you do not use push_back, but allocate your vector before you use it.

Comment: A race condition could be the problem. Maybe it is the most likely one. But there could be other problems as well. Without more information we can't know it.

Comment: Good catch! Had same issue in my multithreaded code with vector pointers and this method worked.